# Sending a string from Arduino to ESP8266 works on UNO but not on Pro Mini

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, esp8266, arduino-pro-mini, serial-data

[image: Arduino Pro Mini wiring][image: Arduino Uno wiring]

I have a project where I am getting sensor data and sending it over to an ESP8266-01 to send to ThingSpeak. After some work I got it to work. So like a real smart person I decided to replace the Arduino UNO I was using (that worked) with an Arduino Pro Mini. Using the same code and connections the String isn't sent to the ESP and then not to ThingSpeak.

Here is a reduced version of the sending code that I used on the UNO and the Pro.

```
#include <FS.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h> //https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino
#include <EEPROM.h>
//needed for library
#include <DNSServer.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <WiFiManager.h> //https://github.com/tzapu/WiFiManager
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
//#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

//SoftwareSerial espSerial(A0, D1); // RX | TX
//stuff to bring in string
const byte numChars = 32;
char receivedChars[numChars];
char tempChars[numChars]; // temporary array for use when parsing
// variables to hold the parsed data
char messageFromPC[numChars] = {0};
float floatFromPC = 0;
float floatFromPC2 = 0;
boolean newData = false;
//end stuff ti bring in string
String f;
String start = "start";
//NEW STUFF START
char Password[36] = "";
char apiKey[16] = "";
WiFiClient client;
//eeprom new end
char defaultHost[100] = "";
//Thing Speak IP address (sometime the web address causes issues with ESP :/
long itt = 500;
long itt2 = 500;
const byte wifiResetPin = 13;
int interruptPinDebounce = 0;
long debouncing_time = 1000;
volatile unsigned long wifiResetLastMillis = 0;
bool shouldSaveConfig = false;

void saveConfigCallback () {
  Serial.println("Should save config");
  shouldSaveConfig = true;
}

void handleWifiReset() {
  if (millis() < wifiResetLastMillis) {
    wifiResetLastMillis = millis();
  }
  if ((millis() - wifiResetLastMillis) >= debouncing_time) {
    Serial.println("Clearing WiFi data resetting");
    WiFiManager wifiManager;
    wifiManager.resetSettings();
    SPIFFS.format();
    ESP.reset();
    delay(1000);
  }
  wifiResetLastMillis = millis();
}
int addr = 0;
void setup() {
  //EEPROM.begin(512); //Initialize EEPROM
  WiFiManager wifiManager;
  Serial.begin(9600);
  //espSerial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(wifiResetPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(wifiResetPin), handleWifiReset, FALLING);
  WiFiManagerParameter customAPIKey("apiKey", "ThingSpeakWriteAPI", apiKey, 16);
  //END NEW STUFF
  //WiFiManager
  //Local initialization. Once its business is done, there is no need to keep it around
  //WiFiManager wifiManager;
  //NEW STUFF START
  //wifiManager.setSaveConfigCallback(saveConfigCallback);
  wifiManager.addParameter(&customAPIKey);
  //END NEW STUFF
  //reset saved settings
  //wifiManager.resetSettings();
  //set custom ip for portal
  //wifiManager.setAPStaticIPConfig(IPAddress(10,0,1,1), IPAddress(10,0,1,1), IPAddress(255,255,255,0));
  //fetches ssid and pass from eeprom and tries to connect
  //if it does not connect it starts an access point with the specified name
  //here  "AutoConnectAP"
  //and goes into a blocking loop awaiting configuration
  wifiManager.autoConnect("AutoConnectAP");
  Serial.println("Connected");
  //NEW STUFF START
  strcpy(apiKey, customAPIKey.getValue());
  if (shouldSaveConfig) {
    Serial.println("saving config");
    DynamicJsonBuffer jsonBuffer;
    JsonObject& json = jsonBuffer.createObject();
    json["defaultHost"] = defaultHost;
    json["apiKey"] = apiKey;
    Serial.println("API");
    Serial.print(apiKey);
    String apiKey2 = String(apiKey);
    File configFile = SPIFFS.open("/config.json", "w");
    if (!configFile) {
      Serial.println("failed to open config file for writing");
    }
    json.printTo(configFile);
    json.printTo(Serial);
    delay(1000);
    configFile.close();
    //end save
  }
  Serial.println("local ip");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  //END NEW STUFF
  //or use this for auto generated name ESP + ChipID
  //wifiManager.autoConnect();
  //Serial.println("WriteApi");
  //Serial.println(apiKey);
  //if you get here you have connected to the WiFi
  //Serial.println("K)");
  //save the custom parameters to FS
  strcpy(apiKey, customAPIKey.getValue());
  EEPROM.begin(512); //Initialize EEPROM
  // write appropriate byte of the EEPROM.
  // these values will remain there when the board is
  // turned off.
  EEPROM.write(addr, 'A'); //Write character A
  addr++; //Increment address
  EEPROM.write(addr, 'B'); //Write character A
  addr++; //Increment address
  EEPROM.write(addr, 'C'); //Write character A
  //Write string to eeprom
  String www = apiKey;
  for (int i = 0; i < www.length(); i++) {
    //loop upto string lenght www.length() returns length of string
    EEPROM.write(0x0F + i, www[i]); //Write one by one with starting address of 0x0F
  }
  EEPROM.commit(); //Store data to EEPROM
  //Read string from eeprom
}

//callback notifying us of the need to save config
void loop() {
  //new stuff string
  recvWithStartEndMarkers();
  if (newData == true) {
    strcpy(tempChars, receivedChars);
    // this temporary copy is necessary to protect the original data
    //   because strtok() used in parseData() replaces the commas with \0
    parseData();
    showParsedData();
    newData = false;
  }
  //new stuff string end
  WiFiManager wifiManager;
  if (WiFi.status() == WL_DISCONNECTED) {
    wifiManager.autoConnect("AutoConnectAP");
  }
  delay(1000);
  if (WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.println("Connected");
    delay(1000);
    WiFiClient client;
    long itt = 50;
    long itt2 = 200;
    char defaultHost[100] = "api.thingspeak.com";
    EEPROM.begin(512);
    Serial.println(""); //Goto next line, as ESP sends some garbage when you reset it
    Serial.print(char(EEPROM.read(addr))); //Read from address 0x00
    addr++; //Increment address
    Serial.print(char(EEPROM.read(addr))); //Read from address 0x01
    addr++; //Increment address
    Serial.println(char(EEPROM.read(addr))); //Read from address 0x02
    //Read string from eeprom
    String www;
    //Here we dont know how many bytes to read it is better practice to use some terminating character
    //Lets do it manually www.circuits4you.com  total length is 20 characters
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
      www = www + char(EEPROM.read(0x0F + i)); //Read one by one with starting address of 0x0F
    }
    Serial.print(www); //Print the text on serial monitor
    if (client.connect(defaultHost, 80)) { // "184.106.153.149" or api.thingspeak.com
      itt++; //Replace with a sensor reading or something useful
      String postStr = www;
      postStr += "&field1=";
      postStr += String(floatFromPC);
      postStr += "&field2=";
      postStr += String(floatFromPC2);
      postStr += "\r\n\r\n\r\n";
      client.print("POST /update HTTP/1.1\n");
      client.print("Host: api.thingspeak.com\n");
      client.print("Connection: close\n");
      client.print("X-THINGSPEAKAPIKEY: " + String (www) + "\n");
      client.print("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\n");
      client.print("Content-Length: ");
      client.print(postStr.length());
      client.print("\n\n\n");
      client.print(postStr);
      Serial.println("% send to Thingspeak");
    }
    client.stop();
    Serial.println("Waiting…");
  }
  delay(5000);
}

//more new stuff for string
void recvWithStartEndMarkers() {
  static boolean recvInProgress = false;
  static byte ndx = 0;
  char startMarker = '<';
  char endMarker = '>';
  char rc;
  while (Serial.available() > 0 && newData == false) {
    rc = Serial.read();
    if (recvInProgress == true) {
      if (rc != endMarker) {
        receivedChars[ndx] = rc;
        ndx++;
        if (ndx >= numChars) {
          ndx = numChars - 1;
        }
      } else {
        receivedChars[ndx] = '\0'; // terminate the string
        recvInProgress = false;
        ndx = 0;
        newData = true;
      }
    } else if (rc == startMarker) {
      recvInProgress = true;
    }
  }
}

void parseData() { // split the data into its parts
  char * strtokIndx; // this is used by strtok() as an index
  strtokIndx = strtok(tempChars, ","); // get the first part - the string
  strcpy(messageFromPC, strtokIndx); // copy it to messageFromPC
  strtokIndx = strtok(NULL, ","); // this continues where the previous call left off
  floatFromPC = atoi(strtokIndx); // convert this part to an integer
  strtokIndx = strtok(NULL, ",");
  floatFromPC2 = atoi(strtokIndx); // convert this part to a float
}

void showParsedData() {
  Serial.print("Message ");
  Serial.println(messageFromPC);
  Serial.print("Float ");
  Serial.println(floatFromPC);
  Serial.print("Float ");
  Serial.println(floatFromPC2);
}
//end new stuff string
```

Sorry for the length but... I don't know if I need to modify how I send the string or I have to turn on the TX and RX pins in the Pro Mini. I have tried connecting the RX Arduino to TX ESP and TX Arduino to RX ESP and RX to RX and TX to TX with no results. I know the pins work because I have programmed the ESP and the PRO numerous times with the TX and RX pins.

Can anyone help me with this? It is driving me crazy.

Comment: Are you using the same connections between the ESP and either Arduino? Cross-connecting RX/TX is correct. The Uno is a 5v device; the ESP is a 3.3v device. The Pro-mini could be either. Did you use level shifters or equivalent with the UNO? Does the Pro-mini both need & use them (5v Pro-mini) or not need and not use them (3.3v Pro-mini)?

Comment: So I tried some experiments.  I had an adapter module attached to the ESP so I removed it and wired directly to the ESP.  I went from the Pro's board pins both RX to TX and TX to Rx and the other way around with no upload, no flashing tx led on board I also tried from the header pins at the end of the board both T

Comment: sorry hit return here is the end of the previous comment  TX to RX and RX to TX and visa versa.  But with no better results.  I usually use level shifters but didn't for the experiment on the Arduino Uno and the Arduino Pro Mini.  Without the shifter it worked with the UNO and not the Pro Mini.  So I don't think it is the pin connections.

Comment: Something about you Pro-min is different from you Uno. (Operating voltage? Frequency? Baud-rate selection?) We don't have enough information (yet) to know what it is, but that's the direction you'll need to take.

Comment: So the ESP is running off a separate voltage regulator 3.3v.  I have tried all kinds of baud rates on both Pro and ESP.  The ESP is supposed to run at 115200 and when I try to reset it it says that the 115200 baud rate is overridden with 115200 but what ever rate I put in the code to override I have to set the serial monitor to that rate to have it read correctly.  The Pro says its normal rate is 57600 but I have tried to reset it and nothing seems to help.  I need a definitive answer.  Is the TXO on the Pro board go to the RX on the ESP and RXI to TX.  this is how I have it set up.

Comment: Here is a print out of the upload form computer to Pro Mini               Using Port                    : /dev/cu.usbserial-00000000                          Using Programmer              : arduino                                                          Overriding Baud Rate          : 57600                                                               AVR Part                      : ATmega328P

Comment: You have the Tx->Rx and Rx->Tx connections correct (called "cross-connected"). "Overriding baud rate...etc" is correct during upload. The boot-loader sets a known baud-rate for uploading, and avrdude on your PC sets the PC's baud-rate to that same value. The word "overriding" is confusing here but just means that during upload, it won't be using the last rates you left them at. ...

Comment: ... Still wondering though, how your Uno and Pro-mini are different. Is each of them a 5v device? Is/was the Arduino & ESP grounds connected to each other? Is/was the ESP being powered by the Arduino's 3.3v power pin (it shouldn't be)? Is the Arduino Tx -> ESP RX connected via either a voltage divider or a level converter (it must be, but the reverse connection, ETx -> ARx, is OK without). Is Arduino using the UART on pins [1,2] or SoftwareSerial (If SS, you'll need to keep your baud rates down to 9600)? A schematic of your power & communication connections would help.

Comment: UNO and Pro are both 5v.  the UNO and the ESP both have common ground and when originally hooked up the UNO is powered by a battery source that has booster to 9v put into Vin pin.  The ESP is powered by the 9v going through a 3.3 v regulator.  On the Pro it is powered by by the 9v booster going to a 5v regulator then into 5v vcc pin to power the board the ESP is powered by going thru 3.3v regulator.  relay is turned on for a brief time to power the ESP with the 3.3v on both so as to save power.  9v going into UNO I think is regulated down to 5v.  I can't think of anything else. both are 16 htz

Comment: If I re-read your post correctly, the connection, Arduino Tx -> ESP Rx, is direct-wired. But the Arduino's 5v is too high for the ESP and may have damaged its Rx pin driver. Does Uno still work? All I can do more is repeat that you or we need schematics of the working- and non-working systems and a more detailed problem description than "... it works great on the Arduino UNO but not on the Arduino Pro Mini". Tough problems need taking a step back and applying a rigorous, complete, and step-by-step analysis. Pls upd your ques with schematics, & clear description of how they behave differently.

Comment: Each time I changed baud rate I reprogrammed ESP using RX-TX so they are working fine. I have read that over long exposure it could fry them but for short periods it is ok. One I have this figured out I will put them in. The PRO I am using is a knock off so that could be it. I have ordered a genuine one from SparkFun and will swap it out when it gets in. I am uploading two wiring diagrams

Comment: The one difference I see between your two schematics is that the Uno uses its on-board 5v regulator and your external 5v regulator seems to have no function. The Pro uses your external 5v regulator. Why the difference? Have you tried supplying the Pro's Vin/Raw input with 9v as you do the Uno? I have no idea why this should be problematic; it's just a difference I see, that I would rule-out. I'd also make the reverse experiment and compare either MCU board being supplied at its Vin from your external regulator.

Comment: I will try that. The raw input on the PRO voltage regulates to 5v so I didn’t think there should be a difference. Is there a way to program the ESP8266 using the Arduino PRO MINI like I do the UNO. that way I would know if the RX TX on PRO board is working.

Comment: You should be able to do anything with the Pro that you can with the Uno. But didn't you say you *were* able to do that (2nd to last sentence of your posting)?

Comment: I program the ESP with the UNO then switch it over to the Pro. I am on the road right now but will try it when I get home. Can’t see why the change in voltage input should make a difference

Comment: I tried hooking up the 9vdc to the raw and disconnecting the 5vdc to the VCC. The PRO shows it has power by the red led but the pins don’t seem to work. At least the #2 pin doesn’t come on when it is supposed to. If I disconnect the 5v and plug in the header power the #2 pin doesn’t respond like it should. I think the board is messed up. I will attempt to remover and replace it. Any suggestions on removal.

Comment: Today I installed a new Arduino Pro Mini and programmed it. The hookup now is the same as with the Arduino UNO shown above. 9v goes to raw input. When connected to the battery everything works as it should except the sensor numbers are NOT transmitted from the Pro to the ESP. I am going to try connecting TX-TX and RX-RX. but I don’t think that will work. Could it be that when I send the numbers from the Pro to the esp, the esp starts broadcasting before it receives the sensor numbers?  Should I have it run longer to see if it gets the numbers for the 2nd broadcast? Still no TX leds in Pro.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got this to work by repeating the Serial.print (f); and then delay(1000); multiple times.  I changed my original post to reflect this.  Somehow this gets the string over to the ESP so it can parse it and upload it.  Now all I want to do is add a temperature sensor and maybe add an IFTTT to the whole thing so if the low end gets too low or the high end too high (of the water level I can get a notification to check out the whole system. 
Thanks JRobert for the help I got the power I needed to the board.